# UIActivityIndicatorView stop animating after minimize app and resume app?

Tags: ios, nsthread, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an upload method which uploads audio with some other data.
Uploading task gets more time. At the starting of this method I start an
`UIActivityIndicator` using `NSThread` class method. `UIActivityIndicator` starts animating.

But my problem is whenever I minimize the app. The app goes into background and after resuming the app only shows the activity indicator without animating. Sometimes the app crashes.

Anyone know what is the problem?